# Make column in CSS Grid dynamic width as small as possible to fit context

Tags: css, css-grid

Is it possible to make some columns in CSS Grid flexible width, to fit the size of its content?

Like on the picture - it's a list item, image on the left, and small info in the top right corner should be of **dynamic width** and fit the size of the content, two other areas should take all the available space.

[image]

It's important to have **dynamic width that fits its content** for those two areas, and not fixed width like x-times smaller than the default grid row.

```css
.grid-container {
  display:             grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'small1 big1 small2'
                       'small1 big2 big2';     
}

.grid-container > .small1 { grid-area: small1 }
.grid-container > .small2 { grid-area: small2 }
.grid-container > .big1   { grid-area: big1 }
.grid-container > .big2   { grid-area: big2 }

.grid-container > * { 
  margin: 5px; 
  padding: 5px; 
  border: 1px solid black; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="small1">small1<br/>small1<br/>small1</div>
  <div class="small2">small2</div>
  <div class="big1">big1</div>
  <div class="big2">big2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure

`grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;`

will do that.

> **auto**
>
> Is a keyword that is identical to maximal content if it's a maximum. As a minimum it represents the largest minimum size (as specified by min-width/min-height) of the grid items occupying the grid track.
>
> <sup>[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns)</sup>

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas: 'small1 big1 small2' 'small1 big2 big2';
}

.grid-container>.small1 {
  grid-area: small1
}

.grid-container>.small2 {
  grid-area: small2
}

.grid-container>.big1 {
  grid-area: big1
}

.grid-container>.big2 {
  grid-area: big2
}

.grid-container>* {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="small1">small1<br/>small1<br/>small1</div>
  <div class="small2">small2</div>
  <div class="big1">big1</div>
  <div class="big2">big2</div>
</div>
```